# Does reset on Cow Evolution reset the crate's upgrade?

Tags: cow-evolution

In Cow Evolution (mobile game, my phone uses Android but is also available for other OS), after I reach Universe cow lvl 4 and reset the Universe, will my crates upgrade be reset? I'm talking about those upgrades that has a chance of showing bigger cows after clicking a crate.

Comment: I assumed that the game in question is the game cow-evolution. Is this right?

Comment: @Mathias711 Yes it is, sorry i couldn't add the tag because of my reputation. I changed the question to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resetted the game a couple of days ago and it does not reset the crates upgrades.

The only progress to be reset are the cows (except aliens) and coins, everything else (aliens, rubies, diamonds, etc) will be kept.

Answer (score 1):

A clarification; the pop up in Cow Evolution looks like this.

[image]

It only resets the home planet.